# Compare two text files and save differences of the 2nd file only

Tags: file, compare, diff

Somebody please suggest me a tool to compare two text files and save the differences of the 2nd text file.

Example

I've two text files

file1.txt with following lines

line1
line2
line3
Line5

file2.txt with following lines

line1
line2
line3
line4

I want to compare these two files and save only the difference of 2nd text file.(ie, the output file contains "line4")

please suggest me a software to do this.

Answer (score 0):

hopes this will help

```
IEnumerable<string> strfile1 = File.ReadLines("file");
IEnumerable<string> strfile2 = File.ReadLines("file");
IEnumerable<string> strfile3 = strfile2.Except(strfile1);
```